# Dynamic Ampscript not showing in Email Inbox

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email, dynamic

I have a dynamic value which is a referral customer go, RAF_ID . Within my email body I have Ampscript `%%=v(@RAF_ID)=%%` in a text box. When I preview and test it, it show the RAF_ID just fine. However, when I send an automated email, the value appears blank within our inbox. Is there something I'm missing here? I've listed my block AmpScript below. Is it because the value is in a text box instead of a code snippet or HTML block?

```
%%[
 
Var @Trigger_ID, @Preferred_Language,@first_name, @last_name,@debtor_number, @Subscriber_Key, @RAF_ID

Var @rows, @row 

Set @Subscriber_Key = AttributeValue("Subscriber_Key")
Set @Trigger_ID = AttributeValue("Trigger_ID")
Set @RAF_ID = AttributeValue("RAF_ID")

Var @rows1, @row1

Set @rows1 = LookupRows ("DE_USN_Enrollment_API_UAT_DE", "Subscriber_Key", @Subscriber_Key , "Trigger_Id", @Trigger_Id, "RAF_ID", @RAF_ID)

Var @rows2, @row2

Set @rows2 = LookupRows ("USN_Master_DE", "Subscriber_Key", @Subscriber_Key)

if RowCount (@rows2) > 0 then
Set @row2 = Row (@rows2,1)
Set @First_Name = Field(@row2,"First_Name")
Set @Preferred_Language = Field(@row2,"Preferred_Language")   
Set @last_name = Field(@row2,"last_name")
Set @debtor_number = Field(@row2, "debtor_number")
endif
]%%
```

Comment: is RAF_ID a field in your sending DE, or a profile attribute or both? And how are you sending, through automation studio or journey builder?

Comment: Just out of interest: Why are you not using the personalization string for subscriberkey? _subscriberkey

Comment: RAF_ID is a value in a sendable data extension. The email is triggered via Journey Builder. When I preview and send a test in email studio with the same sendable DE selected, it shows RAF_ID. @EazyE

Comment: What kind of entry event is the journey? Date based? Contact entry? Data extension?

Comment: @EazyE Data Extension, using the same sendable data extension.

Comment: Access the email's source code, or try to open your email using a VAWP link. If you see the value in the text box, the problem is certainly related to the email client's limitations. If  that's not it, and you're sending yourself a version that renders in the app, but not in your inbox, I'd recommend trying a personalization string instead (%%RAF_ID%%) to confirm it's not an issue with the AMPscript declarations.

Comment: @EduardoArias we previously utilized the personalization string without any block Ampscript, but unfortunately it returned the same blank space in Gmail, Yahoo, and Outlook

Comment: @chorlesbarkley7 if the personalization string returned nothing - then it's likely something connected to the data point. I'd add some debugging code, like making sure the field isn't blank and an ELSE statement to get insight into what is in there.